# Kohana view has 'syntax error unexpected end of file' when called from cli

Tags: php, command-line-interface, kohana-3.3

I have a function which render content of mail based on kohana view.

When I call that function from browser it can render without end file error.

But when I call it from cli it has problem and makes that error.

I tested dos2unix for CRLF and also I checked code for `<?php{` or `}?>` and there is no any these kind of problems.

Is there anyone who can suggest any solution or some guesses about the source of the problem?

Comment: I defined myself, but doesn't matter it works in browser, but the problem is related to CLI and View render of Kohana.

Answer (score 0):

It solved, the problem was that in my Ubuntu server it uses different php for terminal and for responding request from browsers.

And unfortunately settings of them was not the same and then in terminal version it couldn't recognize `<?` as short tag.